# How to check Programmatically the volume of phone in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which i will play music..Now i want to check whether the user has reduced the volume of the phone or not... I want the music to play at a particular volume...How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AudioManager.getStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume%28int%29) to fetch the current volume for the media player stream (See [STREAM_MUSIC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC)), and [AudioManager.setStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) to set it.

Comment: hello femi, I used AudioManager like this.... mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);....Log.i("getStreamVolume",mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)+"");....each time i am getting value as 7

Comment: What happens if you use `setStreamVolume`? Does it change? If you start the music player, then change the volume, then return to your program it should change? Also, you may need the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS)

Comment: Hello Femi... I checked and saw that if i put STREAM_RING instead of STREAM_MUSIC then i am getting the values correctly... Is there a difference between these two as such?

Comment: Basically STREAM_RING is the ringer volume, while STREAM_MUSIC is the music player volume. If you are playing music and you change the volume using the volume up/down buttons it should change the STREAM_MUSIC value, but if there is no music playing and you hit the volume up/down buttons then the ringer volume will be changed.